# Is there any way for your Graph DBMS to reject DML that creates cycles?

Tags: triggers, neo4j, graph-databases

I am a happy user of Neo4j but always need to be careful that cycles are never created. The data structure is a tree you see. It being a tree is important for the specification of the program

With one programmer it's easy. But what about as the program grows and you have dozens of people working on it. Since not all developers have been with you since day 1 and don't have the specification I wrote for the program - they may take shortcuts to achieve explicit project goals, because I didn't specify them, but leave my database in a state that makes some forms of analysis too complex.

Is there something analogous to a database trigger or foreign key referential integrity that stops you from doing something naughty, either in Neo4j or in any hypothetical graph database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any graph database that will allow you to explicitly prevent cycles.  This type of validation logic is specific to your domain and as such, something you must enforce in your application.  Here's some ideas:

- Construct some classes to interact with the graph which abstract away the graph interface and have all communication with the graph from your application go through that.  Write unit tests around these tests to enforce "tree creation only".  In this way your other developers won't need to interact with the graph directly and can only "create trees" with your classes.
- If you were using [Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com) around Neo4j, you could implement a Graph Wrapper (wrappers adorn Graph instances with additional features) that could try to detect cycles as edges are added I suppose, though such checks could be very expensive.  I suppose the chance that something like this would work would be dependent on your schema, graph size, application, etc.
- You asked about triggers, so I would just add that Blueprints provides "trigger-like" functionality through a wrapper called [EventGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Event-Implementation) which will generate notifications as the graph mutates.  You could subscribe to those notifications to perform checks if cycles are being created (again, with the same caveats mentioned above).

All my suggestions are largely all convention rather than configuration.  At the end of the day, a developer may choose to bypass any of the above options and just start writing stuff to the graph.  I suppose that's not much different than any other rogue developer ignoring an RDBMs schema and just creating new tables/columns when they feel like it, so these approaches are no substitution for code review, documentation, etc.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That's a comprehensive list, and gives insight into how people deal with this problem in practice.